PostgreSQL 15 protocol version error with Django and psycopg2 in Docker environment
I'm experiencing protocol version errors while running a Django application with PostgreSQL 15 in Docker containers:
FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 3.0 to 3.0
FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 255.255: server supports 3.0 to 3.0
FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

My setup:

Django 4.2.16
PostgreSQL 15
psycopg2-binary 2.9.10
Python 3.11.4

Docker Compose configuration:
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:14
        container_name: postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"

    backend:
        build:
            context: ./core
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        container_name: backend
        volumes:
            - ./core:/home/app/core
            - static_volume:/home/app/core/static
            - media_volume:/home/app/core/media
        expose:
            - "8000"
        environment:
            # role for entrypoint
            - ROLE=backend
            # basic settings
            - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
            - DEBUG=${DEBUG}
            # database configuration
            - PGDB_ENGINE=${PGDB_ENGINE}
            - PGDB_NAME=${PGDB_NAME}
            - PGDB_USER=${PGDB_USER}
            - PGDB_PASSWORD=${PGDB_PASSWORD}
            - PGDB_HOST=${PGDB_HOST}
            - PGDB_PORT=${PGDB_PORT}
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        restart: always

    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - static_volume:/home/app/core/static
            - media_volume:/home/app/core/media
        depends_on:
            - backend
        restart: always

volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    postgres_data:

The error occurs when I run the docker-compose file, appearing at the end of the logs. Interestingly, downgrading image version to PostgreSQL 14 resolves the issue completely.
What's particularly interesting is that VS Code marks the postgres:15 Docker image as "outdated", while it doesn't show this warning for postgres:14. This seems counterintuitive since version 15 is newer.
What could be causing this protocol incompatibility between psycopg2 and PostgreSQL 15? Is there a way to resolve this while maintaining PostgreSQL 15?
Steps I've tried:
Clearing all Docker volumes
Rebuilding containers

This FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 3.0 to 3.0 and this FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 255.255: server supports 3.0 to 3.0 look like network addresses being supplied in the wrong place.


As to 'outdated', current community supported versions of Postgres are major versions 13-17. I'm guessing the 'outdated' warning relates to the minor version release of 14 vs 15, in that the 15 image is not using the latest minor release whereas the 14 image is. 2) Add to question text the manner in which you are installing psycopg2-binary.

